# e-mail address verification (no regex)

Tags: php, regex, email, function, validation

There was a function for e-mail confirmation. I do not want to use regex. What is the function of a kind I did not think.
and a function for IP validation in PHP's own facilities?

Comment: Send a validation email?  And make sure there are no commas/semicolons in the email (so you don't send the validation to multiple addresses).  I guess you could also try to ping the mail server on the domain they specify.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Check against [PHP's filter_var](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) function. It can validate both IPs and e-mails and several other stuff.

Answer (score 6):

You probably mean the Filter extension, you can find more information about it in the [PHP Manual filter validate page](http://php.net/manual/en/filter.filters.validate.php) page. It can validate E-Mail addresses, IPs, URLs and numbers.